# Can I filter the export of telemetry from app center to application insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, visual-studio-app-center, telemetry, visual-studio-app-center-test

For a particular Android app in App Center, we are collecting all events and exception. Now i want to export the app telemetry to Azure Application Insights but separately for exceptions and separately for all other events.

Is there some way to have separate exports on the basis of defined events?

If all the data went into a single instance of Application Insights, then is it possible to make 2 separate storage as blobs from single Application Insights instance?

Comment: Check this doc, is this what you want.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/analytics/export

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this approach:

- Export **all** telemetry from App Center to Azure Application Insights first using the procedure detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/analytics/export), as George suggested above.
- Set up [Continuous Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry) in Application Insights to then pump your telemetry to Azure Storage.

For Application Insights, data is continuously exported from App Center the moment export is configured along with 2 days of backfilled data. And once continuous export is enabled on your App Insights instance, you will be able to see your raw exported telemetry in a single Storage account auto-categorized into blobs as per the data types selected (Exceptions, Requests, Traces etc.).